# Return multiple values from multiple sheets using loops Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I've included 2 images below which will help to describe what I need to do:

- I have multiple sheets each with a different name
- Within each sheet, there are a number of categories which form a matrix
- I want to return specific values from this matrix to a 'flat file' version

[image: Picture of dummy data]

[image: Flat file headers]

In the above images you can see the matrix with some dummy data and also the headers for the data I want to return: stream, function, region, company, product, original application and target application.

My logic so far has been to create a number of loops which will run vertically and horizontally, using some if/else statements to specify what to return in specific circumstances.

For example if the company name is HB, then return a blank to 'original application' and fill the 'target application' with the cell value - but if the company name is not HB, then return cell values for 'original application' and 'target application'.

I've attempted to de-bug most of what I've written so far, and now when I run it, it simply states 'running' but doesn't actually return anything into my target sheet and I have no idea where the problem is or what I need to fix.

Happy to provide more clarification as I realise this is quite a wordy description.

My code so far is below. Any tips or info are appreciated in terms of making it more efficient as well as help on figuring out my issue, since I am new to VBA.

```
Sub sheetNames()

     Dim rowNumberInMappingSheet As Integer
     rowNumberInMappingSheet = 2

     Call populateMappingSheet

End Sub

Function populateMappingSheet()
     Dim stream As String
     Dim functionalValue As String
     Dim orgApplication As String
     Dim regionValue As String
     Dim companyName As String
     Dim productValue As String
     Dim targetApp As String
     Dim rowNumber As Integer

For i = 5 To Sheets.Count
    rowNumber = i - 3
    stream = Sheets(i).Name

    For j = 7 To Rows.Count
        If (Cells(j, "C").Value = 0) Then
            j = j + 1

        ElseIf (Cells(j, "C").Value = 1) Then
            j = Rows.Count

        Else:
            functionalValue = Cells(j, "C").Text
            orgApplication = ""

            For k = 5 To Columns.Count
                If (Cells(1, k).Value = 0) Then
                    k = k + 1
                ElseIf (Cells(1, k).Value = 1) Then
                    Exit For
                Else:
                    regionValue = Cells(1, k).Text
                    companyName = Cells(2, k).Text
                    productValue = Cells(4, k).Text

                    If (companyName = "HB") Then
                        orgApplication = ""
                        targetApp = Cells(j, k).Text
                        Call WriteRowInCombinedMappingSheet(stream, functionalValue, regionValue, companyName, productValue, orgApplication, targetApp)
                    ElseIf (Cells(5, k).Text = "Current TC application") Then
                        orgApplication = Cells(j, k).Text
                    ElseIf (Cells(5, k).Text = "Target Application") Then
                        targetApp = Cells(j, k).Text
                        Call WriteRowInCombinedMappingSheet(stream, functionalValue, regionValue, companyName, productValue, orgApplication, targetApp)

                    End If
                End If
             Next k
             End If
        Next j
    Next i
End Function

'new function to write

Function WriteRowInCombinedMappingSheet(stream, functionalValue, regionValue, companyName, productValue, orgApplication, targetApp)

     rowNumberInCombinedMappingSheet = rowNumberInCombinedMappingSheet + 1

'writing to a cell in a different sheet

        Worksheets("combinedmapping").Activate

            Cells(rowNumberInCombinedMappingSheet, "A") = stream
            Cells(rowNumberInCombinedMappingSheet, "B") = functionalValue
            Cells(rowNumberInCombinedMappingSheet, "C") = regionValue
            Cells(rowNumberInCombinedMappingSheet, "D") = companyName
            Cells(rowNumberInCombinedMappingSheet, "E") = productValue
            Cells(rowNumberInCombinedMappingSheet, "F") = orgApplication
            Cells(rowNumberInCombinedMappingSheet, "G") = targetApp
 End Function

 Sub activateSheet(sheetname As String)
   'activate the combined mapping sheet
       Worksheets(combinedmapping).Activate
 End Sub
```

Comment: You have a lot of unqualified references, such as `Cells` instead of `Sheets(sheetname).Cells`. Cleaning those up would be good. Also, in "WriteRowInCombinedMappingSheet" you could try writing to cell.value, not just cell.

Comment: Would that be why I am getting a run time error 13: type mismatch on `If (Cells(1, Columns(k)).Value = 0) Then`? Apologies for my ignorance, but by cleaning them up do you mean simply adding `Sheets(sheetname).` as a pre-fix to each of my `Cells` references?

Comment: You could just use `With Sheets(sheetname)` and then just begin each with `.Cells(x, y)`. Also, when you're using `Cells(j, Columns(k))` you could just use `Cells(j, k)`

Comment: Thanks Jordan and Winterkenell. The code now seems to be running but I am facing the following two problems: 1) the code will only write to my target page when I'm on another tab, e.g. 'IT'. 2) The code does not loop. It writes the first line on my target sheet and then stops. Any thoughts?